# Start at position 0 instead of 10

Tags: php

I'm generating a .js file from two database tables and it's working great but now I'm trying to start the $results2 at the beginning (position 0) of the .js file instead of reminder (position) 10.

I cannot wrap my head around this one... Any help is appreciated!

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, name, content, image, cssanimate, group_name FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY id ");
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, name, content, image, cssanimate, group_name FROM TABLE WHERE username = 'admin' ");

$records2 = array();
  while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $records2[] = array('tags' => array($row2));
}

$counter = 0;
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $records[] = array('tags' => array($row));
    $counter++;

if($counter % 10 == 0) {
    $records = array_merge($records, $records2);
  }
}


// Make is pretty
$json = json_encode($records, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


$data = 'var data = ';
file_put_contents('file.js', $data);
file_put_contents('file.js', $json, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: then remove the condition check and use only `$records = array_merge($records, $records2);`

Comment: Your code block appears to have some strange logic.  Why are you constantly merging $records and $record2 instead of just building a single array?

Comment: array_values($records) reset index in array, so you'll get array in sequential order... 0,1,2 and so on....

Comment: Thank you for the feed back! I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my if condition to:

```
$counter % 10 == 0) || $counter==1
```

That did the trick!